# Classes for attributes validation

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, ruby-on-rails, validation, comparative-review

I have two classes responsible for attributes validation:

```
class NameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t('errors.attributes.name.invalid'))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless NameValidator.valid_name?(value)
  end

  def self.valid_name?(name)
    name =~ /\A[a-z][\w\p{Blank}]+\z/i
  end
end
```

and the second one:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t('errors.attributes.email.invalid'))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless EmailValidator.valid_email?(value)
  end

  def self.valid_email?(email)
    email =~ /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i
  end
end
```

They're basically the same. Should I inherit them from one class with protected utility methods or what?

Comment: Can you show how you're using these validators? Couldn't you use [`validates_format_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of) instead?

Answer (score 5):

By creating a base class and then inheriting from it, you end up with no duplication and with an architecture that can be easily extended.

I don't think that you should bother having `valid?` as `protected`. Calling `valid?` from outside is a common use case and doesn't violate encapsulation.

```
class Validator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t('errors.attributes.name.invalid'))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless self.valid?(value)
  end

  def self.valid?(value)
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class NameValidator < Validator
  def self.valid?(value)
    value =~ /\A[a-z][\w\p{Blank}]+\z/i
  end
end

class EmailValidator < Validator
  def self.valid?(value)
    value =~ /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer

Comment: The other reason to keep valid? public is that you can unit test it.